# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.C# asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
Line 19:     
static BalloonShopConnectionString1()

Line 20:  
   {

Line 21:
         dbConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BalloonShopConnection"].ConnectionString;

Line 22:
         dbProviderName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BalloonShopConnection"].ProviderName;

Line 23:         productsPerPage = System.Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsPerPage"]);

Line 21 Error
```

Comment: What is your question here

Comment: you need to tell us whats the problem. No clue what you want exactly.... and btw you dont need to write C# asp in the title. For that there are tags around.

Answer (score 0):

null reference could happen on 21 or 22 if BalloonShopConnection is not defined in your web.config